# CSS psuedo-element (::) within a certain class

Tags: css

I want to customize the scrollbar on my page, but only within a certain div.

I have the code to do it universally:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

but I only want to do this within the div that has the `.return` class.

I tried:

```
.return ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

but this doesn't work.  What's the syntax to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.return::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

You have a space between .return and ::-webkit-scrollbar-track. Remove that and everything should work ;)